# В терминале не отображается ответ от sim800c, но логический анализатор его видит

Tags: консоль, putty, at

Есть модуль sim800c. Запускается, находит сеть. Звонок доходит до модуля.

Модуль подключен через CH340G.

При отправке команды AT в терминале пусто. Пробовал PuTTY и Terminal v1.93b результат одинаковый.

Но при подключении логического анализатора я вижу ответ от модуля.

Из-за чего терминал может не показывать ответ от модуля?

Comment: скорость потока, чётность, количество бит например

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич пробовал разные, но итог одинаковый. При 9600 логический анализатор видит ответ, а PuTTY почему-то нет. Может есть ещё идеи?